# Training Keras model getting stuck with two ImageDataGenerators

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model-fitting

I have built a model in Keras for detecting keypoints of cats. For each image, I have 3 keypoints with three corresponding heatmaps. I stacked the 3 heatmaps together to get a single image with 3 channels.
My model takes an input of size 64,64,3 and an output image of size 64,64,3.

I have created 2 ImageDataGenerators for both images and heatmaps and zipped them together.
I have 30 epochs, the batch size is 32.
When fitting the model, it is not getting out of the training cell!

[image]

The image and heatmap generators look like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test = train_test_split(dataset['cropped_imgs'],test_size=0.20)
y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset['cropped_heatmaps'],test_size=0.20)

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=False,
                             featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                             width_shift_range=0.1,
                             height_shift_range=0.1, 
                             zoom_range=0.2,
                             validation_split=0.2,
                              )

img_train_generator = datagen.flow(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train) ,
                               batch_size=32, 
                               shuffle = True,
                               seed = 1,
                               subset='training'
                               )

img_validation_generator = datagen.flow(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train) ,
                               batch_size=32, 
                               shuffle = True,
                               seed = 1,
                               subset='validation'
                               )


img_test_generator = datagen.flow(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_test) ,
                               batch_size=128, 
                               shuffle = True,
                               seed = 1,
                               )

 
heatmapgen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=False,
                             featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                             width_shift_range=0.1,
                             height_shift_range=0.1, 
                             zoom_range=0.2,
                             validation_split=0.2)

heatmaps_train_generator = heatmapgen.flow(tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train) ,
                               batch_size=32, 
                               shuffle = True,
                               seed = 1,
                               subset='training'
                               )
heatmaps_validation_generator = heatmapgen.flow(tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train) ,
                               batch_size=32, 
                               shuffle = True,
                               seed = 1,
                               subset='validation'
                               )


img_heatmaps_test_generator = heatmapgen.flow(tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test) ,
                               batch_size=32, 
                               shuffle = True,
                               seed = 1,
                               )
```

The model fitting:

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer = opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer = opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_generator = zip(img_train_generator, heatmaps_train_generator)

history = model.fit((pair for pair in train_generator),
                    epochs=30,
                    validation_data = (img_validation_generator,heatmaps_validation_generator)
                  )
```

The only output after 1 hour of training is

```
Epoch 1/30
     66/Unknown - 2305s 35s/step - loss: 0.0455 - accuracy: 0.3345
```

I tried to run the model using TPU but it doesn't seem to be a performance problem. The dataset contains 1700 images which is not that much!
Any idea why it is getting stuck in the fitting cell?

Any help is highly appreciated.